# XML Function causing slow Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

A SQL function that was created by another programmer is slowing down my stored procedure.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be causing a stored procedure to slow down its called in a queries where clause as such

```
AND (dbo.fn_XmlElementDateValue(ua.details, 'start_date') >= @StartDate)
AND (dbo.fn_XmlElementDateValue(ua.details, 'end_date') <= @EndDate)
```

Function

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_XmlAttributeDateValue](@xml text, @tagname varchar(100))
RETURNS DATETIME 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @startpos int, @endpos int, @returnvalue varchar(100)

    IF (NOT @tagname IS NULL)
       BEGIN

    SET @startpos = CHARINDEX('<field name="' + @tagname + '" value="', @xml) + LEN('<field name="' + @tagname + '" value="')

    IF (@startpos > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @endpos = CHARINDEX('" />', @xml, @startpos)

        IF (@endpos > @startpos)
        BEGIN     -- Return the requested value 
            SET @returnvalue = SUBSTRING(@xml, @startpos, @endpos - @startpos)

            IF (ISDATE(@returnvalue) = 1)
            BEGIN
                 RETURN CAST(@returnvalue AS DATETIME)
            END
        END 
     END
   END  --  Tag empty or not found 
   RETURN NULL
END
```

Comment: Show us the code where it's being used.

Comment: This looks like SQL-Server, so it begs the question if you are going to store XML data why not use the [XML data type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx) so you can query it properly rather than using loops and expensive scalar functions?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using the XML type to query XML data. String manipulation is expensive and inefficient.

This would involve changing your function to something like this:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_XmlAttributeDateValue](@xml XML, @tagname varchar(100)) 
RETURNS DATETIME  
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @returnvalue varchar(100)
    IF ISNULL(@tagname, '') = ''        
        RETURN NULL

    SELECT @returnvalue = @xml.value('(//field[@name=(sql:variable("@tagname"))])[1]/@value', 'varchar(100)')
    RETURN CAST(@returnvalue AS DATETIME) 
END
```

And then passing in to the function like so:

```
DECLARE @InXML VARCHAR(MAX) = '<root><field name="test1" value="not interested" /><field name="test2" value="2013-11-04 00:00:01" /></root>'

SELECT [dbo].[fn_XmlAttributeDateValue](CONVERT(XML, @InXML), 'test2')
```

Tested this on SQL 2012.